# jquery - click on children not working if dynamically created

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I created a button tag inside my javascript

```
value = '<button id="structure_' + arrayCodStructure[j] + '" class="ui_btn" >' +   arrayCodStructure[j]   + ' </button><br></br>';
```

and then appended to an existing div this way:

```
$("#listContent").append(value);
```

My purpose is to get button's id when I click on the specific and tried the below code with no luck.

```
$("#listContent.ui_btn").bind("click".function() {
var id = $(this).Attr('id');
    alert("id: " + id);
}
```

Any solution?

selector on **#listContent** works but it is not what I need.

Comment: We have **got** to find a way to make it easier to find the 157 previous versions of this question... *Edit*: Well, it's already pretty easy: If you copy and paste this question title into A Famous Web Search Engine, you'll never guess what three of the top four results are (skipping this question in the results).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, my apologies ...  +1 for the fun joke!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `event-delegation` at this context and the selector that you have used is also wrong,

```
$("#listContent").on('click',".ui_btn" ,function() {
    var id = this.id;
    alert("id: " + id);
}
```